# How to get to detail detail view instead of a alert in table view

Tags: ios5

I want to move to a nib file called DetailView instead of having the alert. I can not figure out how to get this working. I want to bring the data fom the row with me to the new Wiew. I have realy tried to get this to work, but I can not figure it out.

```
#import "TabBarSecondViewController.h"
#import "NSDictionary+MutableDeepCopy.h"
@implementation TabBarSecondViewController

@synthesize names;
@synthesize keys;
@synthesize table;
@synthesize search;
@synthesize allNames;
@synthesize isSearching;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Sök Mat", @"Sök Mat");
    //self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"second"];
}
return self;
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Custom Methods
- (void)resetSearch {
self.names = [self.allNames mutableDeepCopy];
NSMutableArray *keyArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[keyArray addObject:UITableViewIndexSearch];
[keyArray addObjectsFromArray:[[self.allNames allKeys]
                               sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]];
self.keys = keyArray;
}

- (void)handleSearchForTerm:(NSString *)searchTerm {
NSMutableArray *sectionsToRemove = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[self resetSearch];

for (NSString *key in self.keys) {
    NSMutableArray *array = [names valueForKey:key];
    NSMutableArray *toRemove = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSString *name in array) {
        if ([name rangeOfString:searchTerm
                        options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location == NSNotFound)
            [toRemove addObject:name];
    }
    if ([array count] == [toRemove count])
        [sectionsToRemove addObject:key];

    [array removeObjectsInArray:toRemove];
}
[self.keys removeObjectsInArray:sectionsToRemove];
[table reloadData];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sortednames"
                                                 ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc]
                      initWithContentsOfFile:path];
self.allNames = dict;

[self resetSearch];
[table reloadData];
[table setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, 44.0) animated:NO];    

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
  {
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
self.table = nil;
self.search = nil;
self.allNames = nil;
self.names = nil;
self.keys = nil;}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
// Return YES for supported orientations
return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table View Data Source Methods
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return ([keys count] > 0) ? [keys count] : 1;   
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
if ([keys count] == 0)
    return 0;
NSString *key = [keys objectAtIndex:section];
NSArray *nameSection = [names objectForKey:key];
return [nameSection count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSUInteger section = [indexPath section];
NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

NSString *key = [keys objectAtIndex:section];
NSArray *nameSection = [names objectForKey:key];

static NSString *SectionsTableIdentifier = @"SectionsTableIdentifier";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
                         SectionsTableIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
            initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
            reuseIdentifier:SectionsTableIdentifier];
}

cell.textLabel.text = [nameSection objectAtIndex:row];
return cell;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
if ([keys count] == 0)
return nil;

 NSString *key = [keys objectAtIndex:section];
 if (key == UITableViewIndexSearch)
 return nil;
 return key;
 }
/* 
  - (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
 if (isSearching)
return nil;
 return keys;
 }
 */
#pragma mark -
 #pragma mark Table View Delegate Methods
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
[search resignFirstResponder];
isSearching = NO;
search.text = @"";
[tableView reloadData];
return indexPath;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Search Bar Delegate Methods
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
NSString *searchTerm = [searchBar text];
[self handleSearchForTerm:searchTerm];
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
textDidChange:(NSString *)searchTerm {
if ([searchTerm length] == 0) {
    [self resetSearch];
    [table reloadData];
    return;
}
[self handleSearchForTerm:searchTerm];
}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
isSearching = NO;
search.text = @"";
[self resetSearch];
[table reloadData];
[searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
isSearching = YES;
[table reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title
           atIndex:(NSInteger)index {
NSString *key = [keys objectAtIndex:index];
if (key == UITableViewIndexSearch) {
    [tableView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO];
    return NSNotFound;
} else return index;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSUInteger section = [indexPath section];
NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

NSString *key = [keys objectAtIndex:section];
NSArray *nameSection = [names objectForKey:key];
NSString *selectedCell = [nameSection objectAtIndex:row];
NSLog(@"Log selectedCell: %@", selectedCell);

NSString *msg = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
                 @"You have selected %@", selectedCell];
UIAlertView *alert =
[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"State selected"
                           message:msg
                          delegate:self
                 cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                 otherButtonTitles:nil];

 [alert show];        

 }


@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you created a UIViewController for DetailView's NIB?  If so, then create a couple properties in the UIViewController to hold the data you with to push into the new view.  Insure you assign the new view controller and set all necessary connections and delegates in the nib's View Controller in IB.

Then instantiate the new UIViewController where you are calling the UIAlertView.

```
UIViewController *myVC = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
id myValueOne = [myDataOne objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
id myValueTwo = [myDataTwo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
myVC.propertyOne = myValueOne;
myVC.propertyTwo = myValueTwo;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myVC animated:YES];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I still do not get it to work. I am a little bit unsure how and where i declare navigationController to get this to work.

Comment: Look at the documentation for UIViewController and UINavigationController to get more information.  The navigation controller is a property of UIViewController and should in most cases already be there.  You just need to call it.

Comment: Thanks again. I am getting close :) I have the detail view page set up with a NSLog. When I run I can see that the data get to the detail view in the console, but the view does not change. Have I missed something in IB?

Comment: Have you set the values in your properties to text fields, text views, etc.?  If not you can use the viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear methods and set the field's text property to the value in your view properties.

Comment: I just can not get it to work, i am really stuck :( Thanks for your effortt

Comment: Please post your solution so others can learn from your solution.